# ¿Qué significa “javascript:void(0)” en href de la etiqueta a?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Qué significa el valor `javascript:void(0)` en los campos `href` de las etiquetas `a` en `HTML`?

Ejemplo:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btnClick">Click</a>
```

Comment: ¿Alguien puede explicarme el voto en contra en esta pregunta? ¿Que hay de malo en la pregunta?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

El operador `void` evalúa la expresión dada y devuelve `undefined`

La razón de usar esta expresión en un `href` de un `link` es porque este atributo produce una redirección a una versión de texto plano de lo obtenido de la función. Pero si el resultado es `undefined` la redirección no se produce. Esta es la forma más corta de no redirigir y no hacer nada en un `link`.

Diferencias con otros métodos para no redireccionar:

- `href=""` Recarga la página actual
- `href="#"` Hace scroll hasta le top de la página
- `href="javascript: void(0)"` No hace nada
- `href="javascript:;"` No hace nada, pero no funciona en todos los navegadores, por ejemplo, en IE7 redirige a una nueva ventana Y además, no está tan aceptado como estándar de facto que el anterior

Más info:

- Puedes encontrar más info en este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean
- Puede encontrar documentación en este link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void
- Diferencias: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968911/what-is-the-difference-between-href-href-and-href-javascriptvoid0
- ¿Porqué no usuar `href="javascript:;"`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237105/why-use-javascriptvoid0-instead-of-javascript-as-an-href-do-nothing-plac

Answer (score 4):

El operador `void` al igual que otros lenguajes de programación define una función que no retorna un valor.

En el caso de Javascript: `void(expresion)`, especifica una expresión que es evaluada pero no devolverá valor alguno.

Como ejemplo un enlace que no realiza ninguna acción ya que retorna `undefined` ya que evalúa el valor de 0:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> a) Click aquí, sin acción.</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void 0"> b) Click aquí, sin acción.</a>
```

> ¿una variable puede tener void como tipo de dato?

Las variables en Javascript son inicializadas como `undefined`, no puedes usar `void` para definir un tipo de dato  y en realidad no es necesario,

ejemplo:

```js
var myvar1;
console.log("myvar1 : " + myvar1);
var myvar2 = void 0;
console.log("myvar2 : " + myvar2);
```

Comment: Hola @Jet1224 Agrego lo que preguntas relacionado a "¿una variable puede tener void como tipo de dato?"